# Difficulties with $\mathbb Z_3$, $3$-adic numbers and a relative questioning

Tags: solution-verification, modular-arithmetic, p-adic-number-theory, primorial

I'm reading Jean-Pierre Serre's 1970 "Cours d'arithmetique". I'm having trouble reading the beginning of his chapter 2 devoted for example to $\mathbb Z_3$, $3$-adic numbers that I discover and that interest me because of [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4886427/questions-about-mathbb-z-30-mathbb-z) I have about the ring sequence
$$(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z,\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z,\mathbb Z/30\mathbb Z,\dotsc,\mathbb Z/p\#\mathbb Z,\dotsc)$$
He writes

> Let $n\geq 1, A_n:=\mathbb Z/3^n\mathbb Z$. An element of $A_n$ clearly defines an element of $A_{n-1}$

What I understand here is that, if $\textbf{a}\in A_n$ then $\textbf{a}=a+3^n\mathbb Z$. And if we do the Euclidean division of $a$ by $3^{n-1}$ $$a=3^{n-1}q+r$$with $0\leq r\leq 3^{n-1}$. Then $$a+3^n\mathbb Z=3^{n-1}q+r+3^n\mathbb Z=r+3^{n-1}(q+3\mathbb Z)\subset r+3^{n-1}\mathbb Z$$
For example,  $\mathbb Z/9\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ $$0\mapsto0$$ $$1\mapsto 1$$ $$2\mapsto 2$$ $$3\mapsto 0$$ $$4\mapsto 1$$ $$5\mapsto 2$$ $$...$$
Then he writes

> This results in a homomorphism $$\varphi_n:A_n\to A_{n-1}$$ which is surjective, and of kernel $3^{n-1}A_n$

No problem here. Then he writes

> [...] By definition, an element of $\mathbb Z_3$ is $x=(...,x_n,...,x_1)$, with $$x_n\in A_n\land \varphi_n(x_n)=x_{n-1} \text{ if }n\geq 2$$

---

1. Is my comprehension of what is presented by Serre as "clear", correct ? Probably you would have to complete to take another representative of $\textbf{a}$ and make sure that you get the same $r$ and talk about uniqueness.

---

2. I wonder if we can do the same with the sequel $$(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z,\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z,\mathbb Z/30\mathbb Z,...,\mathbb Z/p\#\mathbb Z,...)$$

   For example, $\varphi : \mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ defined by $$0\mapsto 0$$ $$1\mapsto 1$$ $$2\mapsto 0$$ $$3\mapsto 1$$ $$4\mapsto 0$$ $$5\mapsto 1$$

   And if so, what would be the "numbers" we would get then?